# How to evaluate classifier on accuracy and produce roc curve with leave one out in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I have a processing pipeline that I send to grid search that uses leave one out (50 samples) to determine the best model as follows

```
scoring = {'acc': 'accuracy'}
refit = 'acc'
param_grid = {'clf__class_weight': ['balanced'], 
              'clf__C': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0],
              'rf_select__max_features': [5, 10, 15, 20]}
pipe = Pipeline([
             ('rf_select', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)),
             ('clf', LogisticRegression())])
clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=LeaveOneOut(), scoring=scoring, refit=refit)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

I report the best score from this which is based on accuracy, but I would also like an RoC curve.  If I take `clf.best_estimator_` and use the predicted probabilities from the entire set `X` to create an roc curve, will these results be overly optimistic?  The `clf.best_score_` accuracy estimate that I report is averaged across all leave one out sets, but the `clf.best_estimator_` is refit to the entire set.  I worry that using the refit estimator to create an roc curve will produce overly optimistic results.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is valid, of course using the refitted estimator to estimate the AUC will surely be overly optimistic. Usually I would split the data into training and testing prior to running a cross-validated grid/random search for hyper-parameter running on the training portion of the data with refit enabled. Later I would use the testing portion to calculate any other metrics that would be more likely to represent true values, since the model haven't seen them ever before.